# fetching data from external JSON file into an innerHTML table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, innerhtml

I'm trying to fetch data from an **external JSON file** into the **inner HTML** but I can't understand what the problem is. Data is smoothly displayed through the console but nothing is showing up on the HTML page.

Everything looks perfect :(

Please help me identify and resolve this issue

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-stripped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Player ID</th>
                    <th>Player Name</th>
                    <th>Player Country</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="data">
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <script>
                fetch("http://localhost/test.json").then (
                    res=>
                    {
                        res.json().then
                        (
                            data=>
                            {
                                console.log(data);
                                if(data.length >0)
                                {
                                    var temp = "";

                                    //Beginning of the For loop

                                    data.forEach((u)=>{
                                        temp +="<tr>";
                                        temp +="<td>"+u.Id+"</td>";
                                        temp +="<td>"+u.Name+"</td>";
                                        temp +="<td>"+u.Country+"</td>"
                                        temp +=  "</tr>";
                                        })
                                    // --- End of the For Loop

                                    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = temp; //The #tbody ID
                                }
                            }
                        )
                    }
                )
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to display it as plain text? What is your test.json file?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48292679/load-external-json-to-html-table

Answer (score 0):

Javascript objects do not have `length` property. That value will be `undefined`, hence your conditional will never run.

Instead you can do:

```
if (Object.keys(data).length > 0)
```

If you want to ensure it doesn't die when there is no data (i.e. undefined), you can do:

```
if (typeof(data) === 'object' && Object.keys(data).length > 0)
```

Comment: maybe script is running before [DOMContentLodaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) and there is no `document.getElementById("data")`

Comment: In both cases, I got the exact error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.forEach is not a function.

Comment: I tried replacing     console.log(data); with    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

And all JSON records were displayed instead of 3 records only.